# How should I repair, treat or replace crumbling mortar in the floor of my basement corner before laying a concrete slab

Tags: concrete, basement

I'm looking to lay a small concrete slab for a washer/dryer in my basement to level it off and construct a small open enclosure. The brickwork is a little exposed, and there is crumbling of what I can only assume to be mortar or something similar.

The house was built in the 70s so likely lacks proper external insulation, so this will be the first priority after winter, but we need to move some things around and need to place the washing machine down here.

Is this just simply efflorescence? Or decay? It's been this way for the last decade or so, so not sure the extent of the potential damage.

How can I address this bottom corner of the wall, so it might be possible to lay a small level concrete slab?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Removed the phrase with best - as that asks for opinions which is off-topic.  Otherwise it may get closed.

Comment: Looks like you have some water intrusion.